# Monitor cache memory in Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, caching, microsoft-identity-web

We'd like to host an ASP.NET Core 3.1 application in Azure. We are considering to use `Microsoft.Identity.Web` for authentication. In it, there is an option to use `AddInMemoryTokenCaches` (also `AddSessionTokenCaches` and `AddDistributedTokenCaches` [more info here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/Token-cache-serialization)) to store tokens. There is a concern that the tokens could pile up in cache.

If this, first option for cache (`AddInMemoryTokenCaches`) is picked, is there a way to see/monitor in Azure (App Insights or in another place) the amount of cache being used?

Comment: Are you using azure cache for Redis??

Comment: @RajkumarMamidiChettu-MT no, we are using the Distributed Memory Cache (AddDistributedMemoryCache), the one from this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-6.0#distributed-memory-cache